# canceling a published event in Lotus Notes calendar (icalendar)

Tags: outlook, lotus-notes, icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445

I'm trying to create, change and cancel a published event in the Lotus Notes calendar.  I've created ics files that create, change, and cancel events in Outlook successfully.  However, that ics for the Cancel Event bombs in Lotus Notes.  Secondly, I pulled some sample ics files from rfc 5546.  I picked the simplest possible.  I used the iCalendar examples from 4.1.1, 4.1.2, and 4.1.3 from the rfc.  Once again, 4.1.3's Cancel Event ics file fails.  I looked at rfc 2446, and the examples look identical.  Included below are the ics files I've tried with Lotus Notes.  **Does anyone know how to cancel an event with an ics file in the Lotus Notes calendar?**

Here are my ics files:

**examples from RFC 2446/5546:**

create.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//Example/ExampleCalendarClient//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:mailto:alex.m@foo.com
DTSTART:20140709T140000Z
DTEND:120140709T160000Z
DTSTAMP:120140605T130000Z
SUMMARY: Test Class 1
UID:0981234-1234234-23@example.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

update.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example/ExampleCalendarClient//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:mailto:alex.m@foo.com
DTSTAMP:120140605T150000Z
DTSTART:20140709T150000Z
DTEND:120140709T170000Z
SEQUENCE:1
UID:0981234-1234234-23@example.com
SUMMARY: Test Class 1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

delete.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:CANCEL
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example/ExampleCalendarClient//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:mailto:alex.m@foo.com
COMMENT: Class Cancelled
SEQUENCE:2
UID:0981234-1234234-23@example.com
DTSTAMP:120140605T160000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**examples that work with Outlook 2013**

create.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:FooBar Software-566
DTSTART:20140509T140000Z
DTEND:20140509T160000Z
DESCRIPTION:Course: Alex Test Course 19 (classroom)\nFriday, May 9:  Alex Test Classroom 2, Company HQ, 9:00 AM - 11:00 AM;    Time Zone: (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
LOCATION:Alex Test Classroom 2 at Company HQ
SUMMARY:Alex Test Course 19 (classroom)
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

update.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:FooBar Software-566
DTSTART:20140509T150000Z
DTEND:20140509T170000Z
ORGANIZER:support@ziiva.com
DESCRIPTION:Course: Alex Test Course 19 (classroom)\nFriday, May 9:  Alex Test Classroom 2, Company HQ, 10:00 AM - 12:00 PM;    Time Zone: (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
LOCATION:Alex Test Classroom 2 at Company HQ
SUMMARY:Alex Test Course 19 (classroom)
SEQUENCE:1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

delete.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:FooBar Software-566
DESCRIPTION:Course: Alex Test Course 19 (classroom)
LOCATION:Alex Test Classroom 2 at Company HQ
SUMMARY:Alex Test Course 19 (classroom)
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```